# laravel Expression could not be converted to number error how to solve?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

i have the code below which will update the row of the table to add integer value to exisiting row

```
       public function updateValue(Request $request)
     {
  $pp =
    DB::table('table_tbl')
                             ->update(['value'=> DB::raw('value') +$request->val])
                             ->where('value_id', $request->value_id);
   }
```

the error is `Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression could not be converted to number`

Comment: This `DB::raw('value') +$request->val` is not valid...

Comment: what is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this yet but the below query should work.

```
// validate val to be integer before using this query
DB::table('table_tbl')
    ->where('value_id', $request->value_id)
    ->update(['value' => DB::raw('value + '.$request->val)]);
```